Is measurement in quantum mechanics a CPT-symmetric process?
As I understand it, physicists believe that all the laws of physics are CPT-symmetric. That is, if you change a particle to an antiparticle, mirror everything, and then reverse time, the laws of physics do not change.
Now the question: Is measurement in quantum mechanics a CPT-symmetric process?
As I understand it, in one widespread interpretation of quantum mechanics, during measurement, the wave function collapses (at that moment it does not satisfy the Schrödinger equation). It seems to me that in this interpretation, the measurement process is not CPT-invariant.
So does it depend on the interpretation of quantum mechanics? In some interpretations, everything is CPT-invariant, and in others not?

You are correct that if the wave function actually collapses during measurement, then it can't be CPT-invariant.  Obviously, the forward time direction is different from the reverse (since it only collapses in the forward direction) and so T symmetry is violated, and there is nothing stopping us in general from keeping CP conserved during a measurement, so overall CPT is violated.
The wave functions of subsystems (i.e., systems that are not the entire universe) will collapse in any interpretation, so from that perspective the violation of CPT-invariance does not depend on interpretation (the asymmetry in time comes about from the fact that we define a subsystem to look at and then let it evolve forward in time until it collapses; we don't define subsystems and then let them evolve backwards in time).
However, if we are talking about the universal wave function, then there are some interpretations in which it never collapses (Bohmian mechanics, many worlds, etc.).  In those interpretations, we can have full CPT-invariance of the universal wave function.

CPT violation in "collapsed" subsystems absolutely is interpretation-dependent.  The entire class of psi-epistemic interpretations takes "collapse" to be an updated state of knowledge, not mere dynamical evolution.  The state of a (time-asymmetric) agent's knowlege can of course be subject to time-asymmetric updates (looking like a collapse) without requiring any fundamental CPT asymmetry at the level of whatever ontology that agent is gaining knowledge about.  Furthermore, most retrocausal interpretations strive to be perfectly time-symmetric at a fundamental level.

Psi-epistemic interpretations were ruled out by the PBR theorem.  You have a point about retrocausal interpretations though (even though no one has been able to put forward one that is rigorous enough that we could examine it for CPT symmetry)
